# File downloaded using Jersey is corrupted

Tags: java, angularjs, jersey

I am trying to download an Excel(xlsx) file. The file is generated using SXSSFWorkbook and does not have any issue when I open it in server. But when I download it in my angular application, the file is corrupted.

This is my API Code:

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}/download")
@Produces("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
public Response downloadFile(@PathParam("id") long fileId,) throws Exception {
    File target = getFile(fileId); //Another method which generates the file
    return Response.ok((object)target, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
                   .header("content-disposition","attachment; filename =filename.xlsx")
                   .build();
}
```

And this is the Angular code I am using for download:

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.style = "display: none";
var fileType = response.headers('Content-Type');
var fileBlob = new Blob([response.data], {type: fileType});
var fileName = getFileName(response.headers('Content-Disposition'));
var fileURL = fileUtils.createURL(fileBlob);
a.href = fileURL;
a.download = fileName;
a.click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileURL);
```

I am currently using Jersey 1.1, Glassfish 3.1.2 and Angular 1.4.7.

Comment: can not reproduce this. Using curl or the browser is your file still corrupted?

Comment: Yes. Tried using postman. It shows garbled text as response.

Comment: please use Microsoft Excel or OO Calc and create a xlsx file. Try using your code to download that file instead of the generated one and see if the problem persists. I suspect this might be an issue with your excel generation. Try it with the simplest excel file possibl, e.g. one cell "Hello World"

Comment: File generation seems to be working fine. I checked the file on the server location and it opens perfectly. Also if I encode the file as a Base64 string and send it in a json message the file opens perfectly.

Comment: Did you try the test I suggested? How big is your file?

Comment: Yes. Still the same. I am currently working with a 4kb sample file.

Comment: mhm since i can't reproduce this on my machine i would probably need you to host the file in questions somewhere so i can download it and feed it to my server to see what it's doing

Comment: Sure. I will host the file and provide you the url soon.

Comment: you could also look into streamingoutput for jersey

Comment: I tried streaming output also. Same result